# Number of solutions for inequality $3x + 7y + z \leq 198$ in the non-negative integers

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Please explain me how can I calculate a number of possible solutions for such inequality and obtain those values:

$$3x + 7y + z \leq 198$$

where $x,y,z$ are integers (non-negative).

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: It is worth asking what tools/methods/techniques you have available for such questions.  If mathematics software is not available to you (rendering the generating function argument less useful), perhaps you might attempt describing the scenario using [Ehrhart Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial).  If requiring more elementary techniques, I would need to think further on how to approach.

Comment: In searching for a more elementary approach, I came across [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/821246/number-of-non-negative-integer-solutions-of-axbycz-k), but the technique employed there would amount to a great deal of case-work for these specific numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend approaching via generating functions.

First, to account for the fact that it is *less than* or equal, consider the related problem of counting the non-negative integer solutions of $3x+7y+z+\color{red}{w}\color{blue}{=}198$.  The number of solutions of the original question will be the same as the number of solutions of this related question.

We have the following generating function:

$$f(t)=(1+t^3+t^6+t^9+\dots)(1+t^7+t^{14}+t^{21}+\dots)(1+t+t^2+\dots)(1+t+t^2+\dots)$$

$$=\frac{1}{(1-t^3)(1-t^7)(1-t)(1-t)}$$

Using your favorite mathematics software and expanding the generating function, you have

$f(t)=1+2t+3t^2+5t^3+7t^4+\dots+66368t^{197}+\color{red}{67354t^{198}}+68350t^{199}+\dots$

The coefficient of $t^{198}$ is the number of non-negative integer solutions to the equation $3x+7y+z+w=198$, and hence of the original question.